# Set the null value to a object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm working on a external API, where the default value of a object is null.

`location.recipt = null;`

But I need to set `location.recipt.printRecipt` to true, I created a fiddle and figured out unless I make `location.recipt = {}` I wont be able to set `printRecipt`, is there any other solution for this?

Because if that is the case I need to make 2 calls to the API, once to change from `null` to empty object `{}` and then again to update the data.

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/bdeepakreddy/nwemtwtu/

Comment: location.recipt = {
printRecipt : true
}

Comment: But while sending a PUT/POST request, I don't think I can do that right?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to make 2 calls to the API"? Unless the object is frozen you can change its property value right in JavaScript runtime.

Comment: Also, 'receipt' is spelled with two 'e'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
location.recipt={
    printRecipt : true
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a check first

```
location.receipt = location.receipt || {};
location.receipt.printRecipt = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

No. `null` is null (nothing), and you can't set properties on nothing. Instead, you could make your default value be an object with a value property:

```
location.receipt = { value: null };
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do it in JavaScript in one statement:

```js
var location2 = { recipt: { printRecipt: true } };

console.log(location2);
```